# WordPress Customizer and Plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have developed a WordPress theme that uses some custom functions, templates, and post types. While on my test server everything is working fine. When I install the theme on my hosted server, once I install any plugin it causes the Customizer function to stop working. Once there is a plugin installed there is just a blank screen after clicking on the Customizer button. I do not receive any errors with WP-Debug set to true.

Any Ideas?

```
//Functions PHP
    <?php
    require_once('widgets/class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php');
    require_once('widgets/class-wp-widget-recent-comments.php');
    require_once('widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php');

    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

    function expressivegraphics_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    $dependencies = array('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'expressivegraphics-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), $dependencies ); 
}

    function expressivegraphics_enqueue_scripts() {
    $dependencies = array('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', $dependencies, '', true );
}

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'expressivegraphics_enqueue_styles' );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'expressivegraphics_enqueue_scripts' );



    function expressivegraphics_theme_setup(){
        // RSS Feed support

        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        // Translation

        load_theme_textdomain( 'expressivegraphics', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Post Types

        add_theme_support( 'post-formats',  array ( 'aside', 'gallery', 'quote', 'image', 'video','pricing','store' ) );

        // Featured Image Support
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
        add_image_size('slider-large', 1260, 606);
        add_image_size('graphic', 250, 250);


        // Nav Menus
        register_nav_menus(array(
            'primary' => __('Primary Menu')
        ));

        // Logo Support

        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
            'height'      => 100,
            'width'       => 100,
            'flex-height' => true,
            'flex-width'  => true,
            'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
        ));

}
    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'expressivegraphics_theme_setup');

    //  Get Customizer File


    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';


function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-7,-8,-9,-17' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );

    // Widget Locations
    function init_widgets($id){

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Footer 1',
        'id'        => 'footer-1',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h4>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h4>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Footer 2',
        'id'        => 'footer-2',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h4>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h4>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Footer 3',
        'id'        => 'footer-3',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h4>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h4>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Pricing 1',
        'id'        => 'pricing-1',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h2>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h2>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Pricing 2',
        'id'        => 'pricing-2',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h2>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h2>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Pricing 3',
        'id'        => 'pricing-3',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h2>',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h2>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'      => 'Sidebar',
        'id'        => 'sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-default sidebar-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div></div>
        ',
        'before_title'  => '<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3></div><div class="panel-body">'
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'init_widgets');

    // Adds 'list-group-item' to categories li
    function add_new_class_list_categories($list){
        $list = str_replace('cat-item', 'cat-item list-group-item', $list);
        return $list;
    }

    add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_new_class_list_categories');

    // Register Widgets
    function expressivegraphics_register_widgets(){
        register_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts_Custom');
        register_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments_Custom');
        register_widget('WP_Widget_Categories_Custom');
    }


    // Add Comments
    function add_theme_comments($comment, $args, $depth) {
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        if ( 'div' == $args['style'] ) {
            $tag = 'div';
            $add_below = 'comment';
        } else {
            $tag = 'li class="well comment-item"';
            $add_below = 'div-comment';
        }
    ?>

    <<?php echo $tag ?> <?php comment_class( empty( $args['has_children'] ) ? '' : 'parent' ) ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
        <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
        <div id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                <?php if ( $args['avatar_size'] != 0 ) echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] ); ?>
                <?php printf( __( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>' ), get_comment_author_link() ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
                <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.' ); ?></em>
                <br />
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
                <?php
                    /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                    printf( __('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ), '  ', '' );
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php comment_text(); ?>

            <div class="reply">
            <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'add_below' => $add_below, 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ( 'div' != $args['style'] ) : ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        }
```

---

```
    // `Customizer PHP`

    <?php
function expressivegraphics_customize_register($wp_customize){

    // Boxes Section
   $wp_customize->add_section('boxes', array(
        'title'          => __('Boxes', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'description'    => sprintf( __('Options for homepage boxes', 'expressivegraphics')
        ),
        'priority'       => 130,
    ));

   // BOX 1

    // Box 1 Heading Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'box1_heading', array(
        'default'   => _x('Box 1 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'      => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Box 1 Heading Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'box1_heading', array(
        'label'    => __('Box 1 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'boxes',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Box 1 Text Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'box1_text', array(
        'default'              => _x('Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Box 1 Text Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'box1_text', array(
        'label'    => __('Box 1 Text', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'boxes',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Box 1 Icon Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'box1_icon', array(
        'default'              => _x('bar-chart', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Box 1 Icon Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'box1_icon', array(
        'label'    => __('Box 1 Icon', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'boxes',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Box 1 URL Setting
         $wp_customize->add_setting('box1_url', array(
           'default'              => _x('http://www.expressivegraphics.com', 'expressivegraphics'),
           'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
         ));

     // Box 1 URL Control
         $wp_customize->add_control( 'box1_url', array(
           'label'    => __('Box 1 URL', 'expressivegraphics'),
           'section'  => 'boxes',
           'priority' => 1,
         ));     


    //   Contact Box Section

   $wp_customize->add_section('contact', array(
        'title'          => __('Contact', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'description'    => sprintf( __('Options for homepage section contact', 'expressivegraphics')
        ),
        'priority'       => 150,
    ));

   // Contact 1

    // Contact 1 Heading Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact1_heading', array(
        'default'   => _x('Contact 1 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'      => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 1 Heading Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact1_heading', array(
        'label'    => __('Box 1 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Contact 1 Text Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact1_text', array(
        'default'              => _x('Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 1 Text Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact1_text', array(
        'label'    => __('Contact 1 Text', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Contact 1 Icon Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact1_icon', array(
        'default'              => _x('bar-chart', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 1 Icon Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact1_icon', array(
        'label'    => __('Contact 1 Icon', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Contact 2


    // Contact 2 Heading Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact2_heading', array(
        'default'              => _x('Contact 2 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 2 Heading Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact2_heading', array(
        'label'    => __('Contact 2 Heading', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Contact 2 Text Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact2_text', array(
        'default'              => _x('Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 2 Text Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact2_text', array(
        'label'    => __('Contact 2 Text', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

    // Contact 2 Icon Setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'contact2_icon', array(
        'default'              => _x('code', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'type'                 => 'theme_mod'
    ));

    // Contact 2 Icon Control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'contact2_icon', array(
        'label'    => __('Contact 2 Icon', 'expressivegraphics'),
        'section'  => 'contact',
        'priority' => 20,
    ));

}

add_action('customize_register', 'expressivegraphics_customize_register');
```

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools and look at the js console, what you are describing sounds like a JS error. My last one was due to a non-existent variable when I changed some settings, but yours could be totally different.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Thanks Christina, I did have a JS file that I had moved to a different folder and forgot to redirect. That did not solve my problem though. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you read through this list: https://www.mhthemes.com/support/theme-customizer-not-working/. I assume your host doesn't have a lower version of php? What is the PHP memory_limit on your host?

Comment: Read that list, apparently: adding to wp-config.php 

define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);

Worked for many.

Comment: OK thanks again I'll give that a try.

Comment: So it turns out that my hosting company was limiting the memory limit in my account I added define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' ); to wp-config.php and everything works like a charm. Thanks for all of your help.